# Protecting 0/4 - 20 mA loop from over voltage/current?

Tags: protection, 4-20ma

I'm building a device to read 0/4 - 20 mA loop currents using a 250 ohm precision sense resistor. The power source inside the receiver used for driving the sensors is current limited to 30 mA. Suppose that due to some fault or operator error, an external 24 volt supply (that is not current limited) is directly connected to the system input thus putting 24 volts across the 250 ohm resistor. This would result in 2.3 watts of dissipated power. Is there any way to protect the 250 ohm resistor from such voltages or am I forced to use a high watt rated resistor?

Comment: How about a 50mA quick blow fuse in series with the 250 ohm resistor?

Comment: Usually it blows off. In any case you would need an aditional dissipating component if you divert the extra current with a kind of crowbar circuit. I guess you won't find precision 250 ohm resistor for large power.

Comment: Could use 8x 2.2k, a 3.3k, and a 16.5k all in parallel = 250Ω. 2.3W / 8 = 290mW each, so use 1/2 Watt.

Comment: @Andy aka I'm looking for something that would provide continuous protection.

Comment: It can be an electronic resettable fuse - use your imagination - http://www.mouser.co.uk/Circuit-Protection/Thermistors/Resettable-Fuses-PPTC/_/N-axfyt

Comment: @Marko Buršič Do you have specific circuit in mind, because the quiescent current consumed by these circuits introduces errors in the loop current. e.g sensor is putting 100uA on the loop and 50 is being consumed by crowbar circuit and only 50 reaches the sense resistor.

Comment: @hadez No, it was jus my imagination. But you can have mosfet switch, instead. http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbva003/sbva003.pdf

Comment: @rdtsc That is the only thing that came to my mind but I'd rather use an alternative method.

Comment: @Andy aka The "electronic resettable fuse" seems plausible. Time to check out the specs... thanks.

Comment: @Andy aka I checked the re-settable fuses, unfortunately none of them have specifications suitable for the 4-20 ma current loop. I'm looking for a holding current of 30 ma and a tripping current of 50 ma. Unfortunately none of the fuses operate at such low current levels.

Answer (score 2):

A differential Op Amp measuers the voltage on resistor, if it is above level it disconnects for certain time the entire loop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkr038.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I'll have to perform some simulations to see if it's okay within my circuit.